# Explain each step to find $ \int \frac{\cos x\,d x}{1 + (\sin x)^{2}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know the answer but I don't understand the steps to integrate.

$$  \int \frac{\cos x\,d x}{1 + (\sin x)^{2}} $$

Comment: Tryy setting $\sin  x=y$

Comment: You've been 8 month here, but it seems you haven't learnt how to ask a question here

Comment: first you should set u=sin(x) and then obtain du and take simple integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I= \int \frac{\cos x \,dx }{1 + \sin^2 x} $$

substitute $\sin x=t\iff\cos x \,dx=dt$

$$I= \int \frac{dt }{1 + t^{2}} $$
If this seems obvious then we're done

else substitute $t=\tan\theta\iff dt=\sec^2\theta \,d\theta$
$$I= \int \frac{\sec^2\theta \,d\theta }{1 + \tan^{2}\theta}= \int \frac{\sec^2\theta \,d\theta }{\sec^{2}\theta}=\int\,d\theta=\theta+ C $$
By putting Everything back we get

> $$\int \frac{\cos x \,dx }{1 + \sin^2 x}=\arctan(t)+C=\arctan(\sin x)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathrm d\Big(f(x)\Big) = f'(x)\ \mathrm dx $ , we can avoid substitutions for simple integrals such as these:
$$\require{cancel}
\int \frac{\cancel{\cos x} }{1 + \sin^2 x} \frac{\mathrm d\left(\sin x\right)}{\cancel{\cos x}} = \int \frac{\mathrm d(\sin x)}{1 + (\sin x)^2}$$

Now, we know that [$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\arctan x = 1/(1+x^2)$](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQS10SQr8jU)

Obviously,
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{ 1+ \sin^2 x}\ \mathrm dx = \arctan\left(\sin x\right) \color{grey}{+ \mathcal C}$$